Must both conditions of operator "OR ($\vee$)" be defined in mathematics?
I am in the process of writing an article and to explain my question, am providing to you a smaller instance of my wondering so that you can understand it, suppose that $A=\{0,1\}$ and that I define the following quantity, for a vector $v=(1,2)$, $v_1=1$ and $v_2=2$:
$$\forall i\in \{1,2\},\, b_i= \left(i = dim(v) \vee \left( v_i = \max(A)\vee v_{i+1} = \max(A)\right)\right)$$
Definitely, $b_1$ is well defined and equals true. But what about $b_2$? Is it also equal to true though the second term is undefined? $v_3$ definitely does not exists. In computer programing (where this wondering originates from), I am able to compute, in Julia for instance:
julia> A = Set([0,1])
Set{Int64} with 2 elements:
  0
  1

julia> v = (1,2)
(1, 2)

julia> b2 = 2 == length(v) || (v[2] == maximum(A)) || (v[3] == maximum(A))
true

julia>

Note that I truly believe this is not a computer science or software related question. My question is, is it correct in mathematics that in an OR operand either one of the two conditions is undefined but the other one is perfectly fine?
Another example that I thought of could be:
Let $\displaystyle a = ⊤ \vee \left(\frac10 = 0\right)$
Would $a=⊤$ (true) and be defined? Is it something that I can write in correct mathematics? If it is not correct, how could I fix:
$$\forall i\in \{1,2\},\, b^i= \left(i = dim(v) \vee \left( v_i = \max(A)\vee v_{i+1} = \max(A)\right)\right)$$
Such that $b^i$ is well defined for $i\in \{1,2\}$?

What is MWE? And what $n$ refers to? I can't see it being defined anywhere

This is not a software site. You should try stackoverflow and specify your language.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software site.

@RupertRybka, I am sorry, $n$ is a typo and is fixed now, thanks for telling me. I replaced "MWE" with a sentence.

@RossMillikan, thanks for your comment. However, I am sure that I am not asking a software related question.

@AnneBauval, I have improved the title of the question thanks to your comment :)

@AnneBauval, indeed, there were misplaced parenthesis in the formula that I fixed, thanks :)

@AnneBauval, could you try to explain what you don't understand in the syntax so that I try to make my question clearer if you please? Maybe the second example with $a$ would be easier to understand before tackling the main question?

Yes, in general $(\top \lor \text { whatever})$ will evaluates to $\top$. See the truth table fo Logical Disjunction. In general, in classical logic there are no undefined propositions, but maybe the "compiler" can manage the computer program using the logic in the above way.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, even if whatever is pure nonsense, like $1$ divided by $0$? Or whatever is $$v_{i+1} = \max(A)$$ as in the question?

As said, in logic the "nonsense" is not well-accepted... But IF the non-sensical expression can be accepted by the computer program, then the result can be computed. But what about $(\bot \lor \dfrac 1 0)$?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I agree that $$\left(⊥\vee \frac10\right)$$ is not correct in mathematics, and I would not ask for it in Maths.SE. Does that mean, that in a Mathematical paper, it is fine to have a quantity that I reused which is defined with terms like $$\left(⊤\vee \frac10\right)$$ (or the one of the main question)? Maybe you would like to write an answer  :)

$\left(⊤ \vee \frac{1}{0}\right)$ is not a logical formula, because $1/0$ is not a logical formula: it is an expression.  The fact that $1/0$ does not have a defined value is irrelevant: the same would be true of $\left(⊤ \vee \frac{1}{2} \right)$.

@RobertIsrael, thank you very much for pointing this out. I corrected my question thanks to your comment.

$⊤ \vee \left(\frac{1}{0} = 0 \right)$ is syntactically a perfectly good expression, and it would be evaluated as true.

@RobertIsrael, thank you again for your comment. Would you conclude to the opposite of Maura ALLEGRANZA's answer? Would you say that: $$\forall i\in {1,2},, b_i= \left(i = dim(v) \vee \left( v_i = \max(A)\vee v_{i+1} = \max(A)\right)\right)$$ is also a perfectly good expression that would be evaluated as true?

Long comment
Frankly speaking, I do not think that a computer program suitable for mathematics can manage mathematically "nonsensical" expressions...
If we consider a simplified example with $(\top \lor \text {expression})$, where "$\text {expression}$" is some nonsensical string, we have that, due to the truth table for Logical disjunction, it evaluates to $\top$, IF the expression would be accepted by the "compiler".
But the similar case $(\bot \lor \text {expression})$ will be undefined, and thus we would have a strange asymmetrical bahaviour of the program with two formulas that are "structurally identical".
Turning to your main question, if the vector $v$ has been declared having dimension $2$, in my beloved old Fortran a reference to element $v[3]$ will cause an error :-)
In conclusion, regarding the title question:

Must both conditions of operator "OR" be defined in mathematics?

the answer is: YES.

Thank you for your long comment that perfectly answers my question. Just so it remains consistent, I replaced $\left(⊥\vee \frac10 \right)$ by $\left(⊥\vee \frac10 =0\right)$, in case you would like to edit your answer.

@JKHA - Ok, by I prefer to be consistent in using expressions of the same "type" (e.g. boolean).
